# How to Redirect urls after index.php in Laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

We have a classified website developed in Laravel Framework. After analyzing the url structure I am getting the following issue:

> Original Url: https://in.mysite.com/female-clothes/mycity
>
> Duplicate Url: https://in.mysite.com/index.php/female-clothes/mycity

Every url is being duplicated as per the example given above.

Please let me know how to fix the above issue.

I think best option would be to 301 redirect Duplicate url to the Original url.

Please let me know the htaccess rule to fix the issue.

Comment: can you publish your .htaccess ?

Comment: Where exactly are the urls duplicated? Do you generate links that lead to those urls?

Comment: Please check if the `mod_rewrite` is enabled in apache.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which version of laravel?

From what you've said this could be happening in the server (htaccess) or the application (laravel).

Laravel is able to handle url manipulation and redirection. The routing logic is usually found on the file called web.php (router.php for older version). It seems that the string 'index.php' is being inserted in the middle of your urls so look for it there.

If it's not happening in Laravel it could be in the htaccess, so look there as well.

Comment: I have fixed the issue using RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index.php/?([^\ \?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]

Comment: Nice, if you want to make sure you're not redirecting too many times this tool is really useful. https://wheregoes.com/
It matters for SEO purposes, as if you are doing too many redirects google is not able to properly index the end page and show it on google search results.

Comment: Thanks Pablo for your support.